# Table with shaded transitition, rounded corners and shadow (like a block of the theme)

Tags: tables, beamer, themes, shadows, rounded-corners

this is my first question here.

I want to make my table look like the block to have a consequent style.
Questions:

- How to create that shaded transition from the table headline to the body (like the block)
- How to add the shadow. (Different solutions on this forum dont seem to work for my code..)

Here is my minimalistic code which produces the following output:

```
\documentclass{beamer}  
\usetheme{Berlin}  
\setbeamertemplate{blocks}[rounded][shadow=true]

% Packages  
\usepackage[USenglish]{babel}  
\usepackage{times}  
\usepackage{tikz}  
\usepackage{parskip}  
\usepackage{tabularx}  
\usepackage{booktabs}  
\usepackage{colortbl}

% This is for rounded corners  
\usetikzlibrary{calc}  
\pgfdeclarelayer{background}  
\pgfdeclarelayer{foreground}  
\pgfsetlayers{background,main,foreground}

% Define colors  
\definecolor{TblTitle}{RGB}{38,38,134}  
\definecolor{TblBody}{RGB}{233,233,243}

\begin{document}                                                    

\begin{frame}  
\begin{block}{Block 1}  
\begin{itemize}  
\item item 1  
\item item 2  
\end{itemize}  
\end{block}

\begin{tikzpicture}  
\node(tbl){  
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{p{0.5\textwidth}p{0.5\textwidth}}  
\textcolor{white}{Column 1} & \textcolor{white}{Column 2} \\  
\begin{itemize}  
\item item 3  
\item item 4  
\end{itemize} &   
\begin{itemize}  
\item item 5  
\item item 6  
\end{itemize} \\[-1em]  
\end{tabularx}};  
\begin{pgfonlayer}{background}    
\draw[rounded corners,top color=TblTitle,  
bottom color=TblTitle,draw=white]  
($(tbl.north west)+(0.12,0)$)  
rectangle ($(tbl.north east)-(0.12,0.9)$);  
\draw[rounded corners,top color=TblBody,  
bottom color=TblBody,draw=white]   
($(tbl.south west)+(0.12,0.5)$)  
rectangle ($(tbl.south east)-(0.12,0)$);  
\draw[top color=TblBody,bottom color=TblBody,draw=TblBody]  
($(tbl.north east)-(0.13,0.6)$)  
rectangle ($(tbl.south west)+(0.13,0.2)$);  
\end{pgfonlayer}  
\end{tikzpicture}  
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image: Table and block]

Comment: Welcome to LaTeX! As new user without image posting privileges simply include the image as normal and remove the `!` in front of it to turn it into a link. A moderator or another user with edit privileges can then reinsert the `!` to turn it into an image again until you get more rep points.

Comment: Why you need TikZ for that? Can't you simply insert your table into the beamer `block`? Example: `\begin{block}{Column 1 \hspace{0.38\textwidth} Column 2}\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{p{0.5\textwidth}p{0.5\textwidth}}...\end{tabularx}\end{block}`.

Comment: @ClaudioFiandrino your code doesn't compile when putting in a new frame  of my code extract above. or am I doing something wrong ? But putting a table in a box is a good idea, this is what i did: `\begin{frame}
\begin{block}{
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{p{0.45\textwidth}|p{0.45\textwidth}}
  1 & 2 \\end{tabular}
\end{center}}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{p{0.45\textwidth}|p{0.45\textwidth}}
  3 & 4\\ \hline
  5 & 6 \\ \hline
  7 & 8 \\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{block}
\end{frame}`

Comment: My code does not compile because I inserted `...` where you should have put your `itemize` environments.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about this:

```
\documentclass{beamer}  
\usetheme{Berlin}  
\setbeamertemplate{blocks}[rounded][shadow=true]

% Packages  
\usepackage[USenglish]{babel}  
\usepackage{times}  
\usepackage{tikz}  
\usepackage{parskip}  
\usepackage{tabularx}  
\usepackage{booktabs}  
\usepackage{colortbl}

% This is for rounded corners  
\usetikzlibrary{calc}  
\pgfdeclarelayer{background}  
\pgfdeclarelayer{foreground}  
\pgfsetlayers{background,main,foreground}

% Define colors  
\definecolor{TblTitle}{RGB}{38,38,134}  
\definecolor{TblBody}{RGB}{233,233,243}

\begin{document}                                                    

\begin{frame}[t]

\begin{block}{Block 1}  
\begin{itemize}  
\item item 1  
\item item 2  
\end{itemize}  
\end{block}

\tikzset{blocknode/.style={inner sep=0,text width=0.5\textwidth,below right}}

\begin{block}{\tikz{\node[blocknode] {asdf}; \node[blocknode] at (0.5\textwidth,0) {qwertz};}}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[blocknode] {\begin{itemize}\item a\item b\end{itemize}};
\node[blocknode] at (0.5\textwidth,0) {\begin{itemize}\item c\item d\end{itemize}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{block}

\begin{block}{\tikz{\node[blocknode] {qwer wert ertz rtzu tzui zuio uiop}; \node[blocknode] at (0.5\textwidth,0) {asdf sdfg dfgh fghj ghjk hjkl yxcv xcvb cvbn vbnm};}}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[blocknode] {\begin{itemize}\item asdf sdfg dfgh fghj ghjk hjkl yxcv xcvb cvbn vbnm \item b\end{itemize}};
\node[blocknode] at (0.5\textwidth,0) {\begin{itemize}\item c\item qwer wert ertz rtzu tzui zuio uiop\end{itemize}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{block}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Nice thanks! People interested in adding lines in order to separate the cells may have a look here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/66807/table-looking-like-a-block

Answer (score 2):

Instead of trying to make a table look like a block, one could use the `sidebyside` option of `tcolorbox` to place the itemizations besides each other (only the spacing in the header is a bit hacky):

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}

\usetheme{Berlin}  
\setbeamertemplate{blocks}[rounded][shadow=true]

\tikzset{beamer@color/.style={fill=none,top color=tcbcolback,bottom color=tcbcolback}}

\tcbset{
tcbeamer/.style={
  code={
    \usebeamercolor{block body}
    \usebeamercolor{block title}
    \usebeamercolor{normal text}
  },
  skin=beamer,
  boxrule=0mm,
  titlerule=1mm,
  drop fuzzy shadow=black,
  width=\textwidth+7pt,
  enlarge left by=-3pt,
  bottom=0pt,
  top=0pt,
  left=1pt,
  right=1pt,
  arc=4pt,
  outer arc=4pt,
  toptitle=0pt,
  bottomtitle=-1pt,
  colback=block body.bg,
  colframe=block title.bg,
  fonttitle=\usebeamerfont{block title}\color{block title.fg},
  }
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

\begin{tcolorbox}[tcbeamer,sidebyside,title={\parbox{.45\linewidth}{Column 1}\hfill\parbox{.45\linewidth}{Column 2}},lower separated=false] 
    \begin{itemize}
    \item item 1
    \item item 2
    \end{itemize}
\tcblower
    \begin{itemize}
    \item item 1
    \item item 2
    \end{itemize}
\end{tcolorbox}

%
\begin{block}{Test exampleblock}
This is a block provided by the \texttt{beamer} class.
\end{block}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The code can be further simplified with the new tcolorbox inner theme (https://www.ctan.org/pkg/beamertheme-tcolorbox )

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}

\usetheme{Berlin}  
\setbeamertemplate{blocks}[rounded][shadow=true]

\useinnertheme[rounded,shadow]{tcolorbox}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

\begin{tcolorbox}[sidebyside,title={\parbox{.45\linewidth}{Column 1}\hfill\parbox{.45\linewidth}{Column 2}},lower separated=false] 
    \begin{itemize}
    \item item 1
    \item item 2
    \end{itemize}
\tcblower
    \begin{itemize}
    \item item 1
    \item item 2
    \end{itemize}
\end{tcolorbox}

\begin{block}{Test exampleblock}
This is a block provided by the \texttt{beamer} class.
\end{block}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```