# Table looking like a block

Tags: tables, beamer, tabularx, themes

The goal is to create a table that has the same style than a block of the used theme in order to have a consequent style trough the document. this can be done by the following two methodes shown in the code. the last tweak although is to add nice horizontal and vertical lines separating the "cells". I tried this using tabular, but the vertical line is separated, is there any way to get this perfect / do this at all ?

```
\documentclass{beamer}  
\usetheme{Berlin}  
\setbeamertemplate{blocks}[rounded][shadow=true]

\usepackage[USenglish]{babel}  
\usepackage{times}  
\usepackage{tikz}  
\usepackage{parskip}  

\begin{document}      

% Methode 1                                             
\begin{frame}[t]

\tikzset{blocknode/.style={inner sep=0,text width=0.5\textwidth,below right}}

\begin{block}{\tikz{\node[blocknode] {asdf}; \node[blocknode] at (0.5\textwidth,0) {qwertz};}}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[blocknode] {\begin{itemize}\item a\item b\end{itemize}};
\node[blocknode] at (0.5\textwidth,0) {\begin{itemize}\item c\item d\end{itemize}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{block}

% Methode 2
\begin{block}{
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{p{0.45\textwidth}|p{0.45\textwidth}}
  1 & 2 \\
\end{tabular}
\end{center}}

\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{p{0.45\textwidth}|p{0.45\textwidth}}
  \begin{itemize}\item 3\end{itemize} &
  \begin{itemize}\item 4\end{itemize}\\ \hline
  \begin{itemize}\item 5\end{itemize} &
  \begin{itemize}\item 6\end{itemize} \\ \hline
  \begin{itemize}\item 7\end{itemize} &
  \begin{itemize}\item 8\end{itemize} \\
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{block}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Please have a look at this [why-not-use-vertical-lines-in-a-tabular](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/40542/why-not-use-vertical-lines-in-a-tabular)

Comment: I think also that vertical lines are not very nice

Comment: There’s basically [the same question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/74197/beamer-tables-like-block-structure-look-and-feel) with a different answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In method 2, you can make a empty block caption and then up a little the table:

```
\documentclass{beamer}  
\usetheme{Berlin}  
\setbeamertemplate{blocks}[rounded][shadow=true]

\usepackage[USenglish]{babel}  
\usepackage{times}  
\usepackage{tikz}  
\usepackage{parskip}  

\begin{document}      

\begin{frame}[t]

% Methode 2
\begin{block}{~\vspace{0.7cm}}
\begin{center}
\vspace{-0.8cm}
\begin{tabular}{p{0.45\textwidth}|p{0.45\textwidth}}
 \textcolor{white}{\bf Head 1} & \textcolor{white}{\bf Head 2} \\
  \begin{itemize}\item 3\end{itemize} &
  \begin{itemize}\item 4\end{itemize}\\ \hline
  \begin{itemize}\item 5\end{itemize} &
  \begin{itemize}\item 6\end{itemize} \\ \hline
  \begin{itemize}\item 7\end{itemize} &
  \begin{itemize}\item 8\end{itemize} \\
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{block}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image: block with table]