# Oversized colored row in beamer block

Tags: tables, beamer, color

As a follow up to [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/66807/table-looking-like-a-block) question, I am trying to insert tables in my beamer presentation so that they have the same style as blocks. However, I want to avoid using rules in my tables, and I am trying to used colored rows (with package `xcolor`) to improve readability.

Here is an example of my code:

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{table}{xcolor}
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{tabularx}

\definecolor{RowColorOdd}{rgb}{0.914,0.914,0.953}
\definecolor{RowColorEven}{rgb}{1,1,1}

\usetheme{Darmstadt}
\usecolortheme{seahorse}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[plain]
  \begin{block}{\centering\begin{tabularx}{1\textwidth}{@{}p{0.56\textwidth}@{}X@{}X@{}}\textcolor{white}{Header 1} & \textcolor{white}{Header 2} & \textcolor{white}{Header 3}\end{tabularx}}%
  \centering
    \rowcolors{1}{RowColorOdd}{RowColorEven}%
    \begin{tabularx}{1\textwidth}{@{}p{0.56\textwidth}@{}X@{}X@{}}%
      1.1 & 1.2 & 1.3 \\%
      2.1 & 2.2 & 2.3 \\%
      3.1 & 3.2 & 3.3 \\%
      4.1 & 4.2 & 4.3
    \end{tabularx}%
  \end{block}%
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

However, this code results in the following table, where rows are oversized with respects to the block frame:
[image: Result]

Any idea how I can fix this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

for both tabular use:

```
\begin{tabularx}{\dimexpr\textwidth-2\tabcolsep}{@{}p{0.56\textwidth}@{}X@{}X@{}}%
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I understand your solution, and it works, but now the rows are undersized w/r to the block, probably due to the block inner margins. Is there a way to take these margins into account so that the rows are exactly as wide as the block ?

Comment: use it for both tabulars. The box has an inner border. You can use as an alternative  package `tcolorbox`